# What is the purpose of this JS pattern?

Tags: javascript

I am looking through someone else's code and I see this pattern being applied:

```
var MyObj = function(){

 this._myHiMember = this.assignHi();

};

 MyObj.prototype = {
   assignHi : function(){ return 'hi, ppl';}
};
```

What is the purpose of creating a reference on the instance to the method on the prototype?

Answer (score 4):

Properties of the prototype object are defined once but inherited by all instances which reference it.

The document [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) has a good treatise on the subject.

Could it be this fact the original programmer is trying to take advantage of?

Answer (score 2):

If a function is declared as part of the prototype then only one copy of that function is created. If you create it in the constructor you create a new copy for every instance.